# Cython pure python mode

Tags: python, cython

I have a simple `test.py` file where I want to add types using Cython. To stay python interpreter compatible, I use the pure python mode. I added:

```
import cython
```

And then try to define a type by:

```
d = cython.declare(cython.dict)
```

Then the python interpreter in Eclipse gives me an error on this line:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dict'

What did I miss? When I rename test.py to test.pyx it works, but I want to keep it as a .py file to be able to import it in other python files.

Comment: That works! Should be mentioned in the cython documentation. If you write it as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `d = cython.declare(dict)`